# Multiple batches in a SQL transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, transactions

I want to create several stored procedures (or user-defined functions) within a transaction. `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement must be the only statement in the batch, so I have to use following template:

```sql
BEGIN TRANSACTION MyTransaction

    USE MyDatabase
    GO

    CREATE PROCEDURE A
    AS
        -- The body of procedure A
    GO

    CREATE PROCEDURE B
    AS
        -- The body of procedure B
    GO

    CREATE PROCEDURE C
    AS
        -- The body of procedure C
    GO

COMMIT TRANSACTION MyTransaction
```

The problem appears if an error occurs within one of the batches. For example, if error occurs while procedure **B** is creating, `MyTransaction` with procedures **A** and **B** will be rolled back. But the script will continue to run. So, the procedure **C** will be created.

Also it's not possible to skip the statement using `GOTO` and `@@error` counter checking, because it cannot go to a label outside the batch in which `GOTO` is placed.

How to prevent any database changes if an error occurs?

Comment: Use `TRY....CATCH`. And, since you already want a transaction, you need the very frequent try-transaction block: search for it on google, in here, or here is a good one:   http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html#jumpgeneralpattern

Comment: @cheffe, the idea is good. But I hope to find a way to make changes using standard tools of SSMS.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis, I like your suggestion! I will try it some later and give you feedback.

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis, it does not work. The problem is the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement in accordance with [Limitations and Restrictions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#limitations-and-restrictions) cannot be combined with other Transact-SQL statements in a single batch. 
On the other hand a `TRY...CATCH` construct cannot span multiple batches (see [remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-2012#remarks)).

Comment: OK. You mention that if B fails, the transaction rolls back. But I see no rollback statements in your code; are you using `xact_abort on`?

Comment: @GeorgeMenoutis, yes. The `xact_abort` is `on` by default on my server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to do something like this with **SET XACT_ABORT ON**.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tempdb..sysobjects WHERE id=OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tmpErrors')) DROP TABLE #tmpErrors
GO
CREATE TABLE #tmpErrors (Error int)
GO
SET XACT_ABORT ON
GO
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE
GO
BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO
PRINT N'Creating [Proc A]'
GO
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE PROCEDURE A
    AS
        -- The body of procedure A
    GO
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

IF @@ERROR<>0 AND @@TRANCOUNT>0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
GO
IF @@TRANCOUNT=0 BEGIN INSERT INTO #tmpErrors (Error) SELECT 1 BEGIN TRANSACTION END
GO
PRINT N'Creating [Proc B]'
GO
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE PROCEDURE B
    AS
        -- The body of procedure B
    GO
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
IF @@ERROR<>0 AND @@TRANCOUNT>0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
GO
IF @@TRANCOUNT=0 BEGIN INSERT INTO #tmpErrors (Error) SELECT 1 BEGIN TRANSACTION END
GO
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #tmpErrors) ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
GO
IF @@TRANCOUNT>0 BEGIN
PRINT 'The database update succeeded'
COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
ELSE PRINT 'The database update failed'
GO
DROP TABLE #tmpErrors
GO
```

Comment: It seems bulky but it works.. Actually, it creates additional transaction if an error occurs, and then rolls back it, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes.
When SET XACT_ABORT is ON, if a Transact-SQL statement raises a run-time error, the entire transaction is terminated and rolled back.
When SET XACT_ABORT is OFF, in some cases only the Transact-SQL statement that raised the error is rolled back and the transaction continues processing.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-xact-abort-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017